# Securing my REST API to be used with only my apps?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, app-id

I want to build a REST API on a server. Say api.xyz.com, which will contain a jwt based user authentication system. I want to build different clients. Say one for android and one for a web app. How do I prevent other people to use my routes in their clients ? Is there any way ? Should I change my design principle to achieve this ?

Comment: add a login/authentication system, basically...

Comment: You can also add some parameter at the header.

Comment: Or use tokens which are consumed and (re-)distributed....so many options. Just google a little and pick one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by sharing an authentication cookie between the main domain and the API sub domain if it concerns a web site.

A common way to solve this problem when it comes to apps, is using an token based authenication system, like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/), which is currently at version 2.

Comment: @Sanjit: was this answer helpful to you?